# Apostrophe in char data type

Tags: c, arrays, char, structure, apostrophe

```
char c; 
c = '2';
printf("%d\n",c);
```

So this question is from my quiz, it is asking what is the display. The answer is 50, i tried by using program, but why it is 50? not 2 or anything?

Comment: It seems your system (like most systems today) is using [the ASCII character set](http://www.ascii-code.com/). If you check the link, you might understand why `'2' == 50`.

Comment: Also, please try to come up with better titles for your questions in the future. The question has nothing to do with apostrophes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apostrophes mean "character literal", i.e. `'2'` is not the integer 2, but instead the character 2, i.e. the glyph used to represent the single digit 2.

You print this value using `%d` in `printf()`, which means "signed integer", so you get the integer value of the character, often called the "code point" (or, classically, it's "ASCII value").

I think your code is not 100% clean, since `char` might be `unsigned`, you should cast to `(int)` in the call to be clear, since `int` is what `%d` expects.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing a `char '2'`, as an `int '%d'`, so what gets printed, is its `ASCII value`